# i want to know that on admin panel from which website i'll recieve a message from?

Tags: popup, client, chat, admin, chatbot

I designed a chat popup with an admin panel and the chat popup is already uploaded on different websites in which the visitors send a message to the supporters. Still, I want to know from which website I receive a message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send window.location.href value from the popup to the supporter.
This value should be sent as a system message which is not a regular chat message but a hidden message dedicated to sending technical informations.
You can send the message at the beginning of the connection.